# Interferometry's arch nemesis: CLOCKS

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, oscillator, clock

I have a problem and it spans easily 4 Stack Exchange forums so let's wrap up quick here. I'm doing radio astronomy. I'm setting up interferometry among 3 radio telescopes. (I'm using three PCB's with cheap clocks and if they aren't perfectly synchronized my data is worthless).

**How would you go about stabilizing the oscillators of three circuits?**

First off, the PCB is this: http://erewhon.superkuh.com/gnuradio/rtlsdr_QS_FSC_USB_DVB-T.jpg 
It's basically a multimeter aka a radio receiver made for television stations. On the up side it has spectacular bandwidth, it covers 30MHz to 1.7GHz for 10$ CAD. Also note: `tuner error is ~30 +-20 PPM` which is awful, but when you can only afford to eat oatmeal, it's beautiful to even have electricity.

Details required to solve this question

**Possible Operating Frequencies:** 1420MHz, 950MHz, 2150MHz 
**Diameter of the Interferometer:** 30-40 feet. 

**Acceptable Phase Stability of:** 1/1000% Cycle Error

**Possible Solution**

Why not simply desolder the clocks from two of the PCB's and solder a copper shielded cable from the one PCB I didn't desolder? That's o.k. but if I liked that solution I wouldn't have asked. **NOTE** It's pretty crummy and when I do get a "round-tuit" (probably one in the garage) I'll purchase better circuits- but guess what? Their clocks will also be problematic so let's solve it with the worst hardware, that way any hardware will work.

Comment: It has come to my attention that not every electrical engineer or enthusiast understands why clocks matter in interferometry or fully understand my problem. For comprehensive background check out this question and my answer: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20082/how-does-the-event-horizon-telescope-implement-the-interferometry/24315#24315

Comment: How far apart are your telescopes and how precisely do you need to align the clocks? "Perfectly" is not a useful spec for engineering.

Comment: I don't think you stabilize and synchronize the existing oscillators.  I think the solution is to have one very good (precise) oscillator which you distribute to your devices.

Comment: Good point, what I need is to make sure the clocks do not deviate. If they're off by 1/4 cycle that's fine, but if one gradually increases how far off it is say to 1/2 cycle over 24hours, houston we have a major problem. They're no more than 20 ft apart in either direction from the primary dish (telescope). A goal would be to maintain say 1/1000 deviation max.

Comment: Thanks JRE, that's essentially what my o.k. solution was- if you think it's the best solution then perhaps it's my _only_ solution.

Comment: When I researched something like this a few years ago I found a decent report from SLAC on distributing clocks around their accelerator (much more than 20 ft in diameter). If you can find it it might give some ideas.

Comment: You're looking for 6 mrad phase stability. But you haven't said what's your operating frequency. If you're working at 1 MHz, this is not too hard. If you're working at 10 GHz, then thermal variations, even in teflon cable, will mess up a clock distribution network.

Comment: The Photon is clearly awesome. Will require further research into it, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.08050.pdf begins with language I can already just barely tolerate. But laser stability is rather important and is mutual for my case. Operating frequency will vary depending on the celestial object being observed. If I'm looking at hydrogen lines I'll be working around 1420MHz. If I'm using an LNB to shift down some seriously high frequency I'll be dropping it to a standard 950–2150 MHz.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the information needed to answer it: Operating frequency, phase stability requirement, diameter of the system, ...

Comment: It isn't the only solution.  It is a solution in line with a budget that includes software radio dongles as a major line item.  I've been trying to imagine how to build a backyard radio telescope for a while now.  Sometimes I think a single large dish would be simpler, sometimes I think several smaller ones and interferometry would be simpler.  In either case, cost is a major factor.

Comment: If you use LNBs, won't you have to synchonize their local oscillators as well?

Comment: Been thinking about this.  Synchronized clocks on the boards still don't mean your samples are synchronized.

Comment: JRE that's exactly my problem. I don't mean the clocks have to be synched I mean they can't deviate. Hence linking the other SE article. If they're off by 1/4 cycle that's fine. If they slowly increase how far off they are then it ruins my data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several alternatives.

The first is to go for some form of common clock distribution. But not all ways of doing this are obvious!

The second is to go for a short enough observation, and high enough accuracy clocks, that the accumulated phase drift over your observation is within your interferrometry reconstruction budget.

Taking the second option, your potential clock sources, from very low cost very low accuracy, to very high cost very high accuracy, go roughly RC, LC, ceramic resonator, crystal, TCXO, ovened crystal, rubidium, caesium, and atomic fountain. Match your accuracy budget with your financial budget, and see whether there is a solution.

When using clock distribution, first consider how it's used on each PCB. Each PCB can either use the distributed clock signal directly, or can have a slave crystal oscillator, which is PLL'd to the distributed signal. This will degrade the long term phase error due to PLL noise, but will clean up any high frequency phase noise on the distributed clock, and can potentially allow a much greater variety of synchronising sources.

Options are many - a coax cable from the master oscillator, or it could be a radio signal. Optical distribution is also possible. Alternatively each PCB could use a GPS receiver, or a receiver for some other radio service.

Finally, each PCB could be entirely free-running, as in the first option. However, you could broadcast an in-band fake radio object signal with known characteristics, visible to all the antennae, often called a beacon. This signal must be small enough to not eat into the dynamic range of the receivers too much, but large enough to be well out of the noise. Demodulate the beacon, correcting the phases of the local clocks to give the sharpest picture. Now use the same clock phase correction to reconstruct the rest of the picture. As the beacon is known to be stable, long averaging can reduce the amount of beacon phase noise that will be impressed onto the clocks.

This latter one uses the same concept for the way adaptive mirror telescopes can look through an unstable atmosphere (arguably an optical interferometer with poor phase stability across the aperture) and correct the image, they move the mirrors (alter the phase shift of different paths) for best reconstruction of a laser-transmitted [guide star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_guide_star).

Comment: Beacon seems a neat idea, but may run afoul of near-field reflectors like wildlife, swaying trees, passing vehicles.

Comment: Hi Neil, I love the variety of solutions you've given me, I hadn't thought of a beacon before that's an interesting concept- my only concern is that the interferometer is trying to sample something with such a low gain that it may interfere. HOWEVER there already is this massive "beacon" which sits at the marine band causing interference on literally every freaking signal I work with: NOAA Weather Service. I also like the idea of the clocks being sent their oscillations over radio for larger aperture setups. Also thank you for the advice on short observations using high precision hardware.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with desoldering the oscillator on one board and replacing its output with a signal from another board. It's exactly what I did when I needed to synchronize two GPS receivers in order to do short-baseline GPS interferometry (a way of getting absolute attitude information), and it worked like a charm.

The key is to keep the receivers physically close to each other. I used short lengths of twisted pair to make the connections between the boards. Use matched lengths of coax to bring the signals from the antennas to the receivers.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's a practical solution that really concerned me at first but as I mentioned in my question I will slowly upgrade the hardware to be less noisy and higher spec. If I can get it to work on my cheap PCB's I'll feel more confident about doing it to higher level equipment. I appreciate the example and application you used in your answer that really makes me feel confident about applying the solution in the future.

Comment: @Tmanok - you're goofing around with 8-bit ADCs - I have one too and it's fun for picking up nearby transmissions, but unless you put serious attention into your front end, the whole experiment is laughable.  Distributing a reference signal the norm for serious gear, which is why serious gear has an input connectors for it...

Answer (score 0):

As you upgrade, keep in mind the realities of jitter.

TimeJitter = Vnoise / SlewRate

For 0.1% jitter at 10GigaHertz (100 picosecond period), you need 10 femto seconds of jitter.

Assuming SlewRate is 10 volts / nanosecond on the clocking edge, the Vnoise must be

Vnoise = TimeJitter * SlewRate =10e-15 seconds * 10 volt/1e-9 seconds

Vnoise = 100 * 10^-6 volts rms or 0.1 milliVolts

Is that achievable? In a 120 ohm Rnoise system (tough to accomplish), in 10 Gigahertz bandwidth, the total (integrated) noise is 1nanoVolt * sqrt(2) * sqrt(10 Gigahertz) = 1.414nanoVolts * 100,000 = 141,000 nanovolts = 141 microvolts
= 0.141 millivolts

Low jitter systems are difficult. Hope this math and concepts are helpful.

Comment: Thanks AnalogsysRF, I'm trying to understand whether you're talking about the ADC Clock or the Local Heterodyne Clock when you speak of jitter. The math does appear to make sense except did you mean 10 Volt / 10e-9s? (7th line with text).